# Import from testing package to main package

Tags: java, gradle

Right now I'm working as an Intern in a larger company and one of my task is to migrate everything from eclipse to intellij and from maven to gradle.

One problem is, that they have one  class in the main package with the dependencies to a test class or better say to the test class's package.

the main package is `com.companyname`.
the test package is `com.companyname`

So it's the same name but separated in different folders like `src/main` and `src/test`

So class A wants to import from Test Class B but of course it's not possible by default, gradle throws an error that the dependency

I hope everything is understandable, I'm not allowed to post any code, if you got any questions please let me know.
I already asked them if it's correct as they do it and they said to me yes, so I'm not in charge of the project itself. But they also don't know gradle or intellij

Edit: Testing Framework is cucumber

Comment: You can suggest for some code refactoring, so no test classes are referred in the main classes as that is quite a non-sense

Comment: Did the exact same thing you just said, but they said it's working so no changes needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two possibilities:

1. The class from the *test* code is really needed in the  *production* code.
   In that case the class should be moved to `src/main/java/...`
2. The usage of the *test* code from *production* code is a mistake.
   In that case  the production code should be updated not to use the test code.

Either way the build configuration is **not** the place to fix this.

Report the problem to your team leader and let her decide how to proceed.

Comment: @Noobienoob from your description they don't have "working code". They have a hidden problem. And If they refuse to fix that now it will grow. BTW: don't you use a SCM doing your work in a dedicated branch?

Comment: @Noobienoob *"they don't listen to an intern... "* you talk about extern contractors refusing to clean up their mess?

Comment: @Noobienoob *"they are using git"* [...] *"he launch of the product is this or next week.."* - still no reason to refuse the change. As mentioned this could be don in a separate branch and mergerd (or better rebased) into/onto master after the launch. **--**  However, *"intern in the sense of internship"* You should think really carefully if this is the right team to learn from.